# Variable Not Defined - Microsoft Access

Tags: variables, undefined, ms-access-2013

I have created a script in Microsoft Access for my login button. I want the button to verify the users name, password, and security level before taking them to the appropriate screen that's designated just for that user. I don't want them to be able to see other information so I know that I will need to secure my front end (back end already secured). This is my code and the error I get when debugging is variable not defined -

```
enter code here

Option Compare Database


Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblUsers", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

   rs.FindFirst "UserName= '" & Me.txtUserName & "'"

   If rs.NoMatch = True Then
   Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = True
   Me.txtUserName.SetFocus

   Exit Sub

End If
    Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False

    If rs!Password <> Me.txtPassword Then
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = True
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus

Exit Sub

End If
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = False

If UserSecrityLevel = 1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "AdminDashboard"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

    Exit Sub

End If

If rs!UserSecurityLevel = 3 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "PSAdmiinDashboard"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

    Exit Sub

End If

If rs!UserSecurityLevel = 2 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "CollectionsDashboard"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

    Exit Sub

End If

If rs!UserSecurityLevel = 4 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ProcurmentDashboard"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Exit Sub

End If





End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post a *minimal example* of your problem as well as the *complete* error message?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you misspelled UserSecurityLevel and  missed the rs! in the following

```
If UserSecrityLevel = 1 Then
   ... etc
```

It should be

```
If rs!UserSecurityLevel = 1 Then
       ... etc
```

Because of this, **UserSecrityLevel** is being interpreted as an undefined variable

Wing